# NoMethod Error private method ActionMailer rails 4 sending email after record save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, nomethoderror

I am new to rails and I'm making an app where a user can create a Post. I am trying to trigger a confirmation email after a user posts a Post....but I keep getting this NoMethod Error:

```
"private method `add_post' called for PostMailer:Class"
```

I've tried restarting and even not passing params.  I have no idea what's going on. My ActionMailer logic is not encased in a 'private method'...as far as I know.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def add_post
    @magazine = Magazine.find(params[:m])
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        PostMailer.add_post(@post, @magazine, current_user).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to postadded_path(), notice: "Post Added."}
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end
```

The ActionMailer Logic

```
class PostMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def add_post(post, magazine, current_user)
    @magazine = magazine
    @post = post
    @recipient = current_user.email
    mail(to: @recipient, subject: 'You've Posted an Article',   sent_on: Time.now,   template_path: 'add_post_email') 

  end
```

Comment: That's so weird. Does the following work? `PostMailer.send(:add_post, @post, @magazine, current_user).deliver`

Comment: Thank you for answering,  I'v just come back to put that I had and extra "end" right below "class PostMailer < ActionMailer::Base
"....totally my error.  I'm going to edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...this was totally my problem.  I left and "end" below "class PostMailer < ActionMailer::Base
" like this.  So my logic was right, but my error was ending the class before the logic could be read. Simple error, hours of headache.

```
class PostMailer < ActionMailer::Base
end 

def add_post(post, magazine, current_user)
    @magazine = magazine
    @post = post
    @recipient = current_user.email
    mail(to: @recipient, subject: 'You've Posted an Article',   sent_on: Time.now,   template_path: 'add_post_email') 
  end
```